# Logic Circuits in Lyx

Tags: lyx, logic

I'm unsure as to how I should be compiling this on LyX. I remember seeing others use LaTeX to form circuit boards with certain preambles, but since this is on LyX, I was completely unsure of how it would be done here. Do I need to add certain preambles? I'm unsure as to how to do this on LyX, or if it even can be done in the first place...

Comment: You can use `circuitikz` or the Ti*k*Z library of logic gates. In both cases, you should probably follow https://wiki.lyx.org/Tips/UsingTikZ-PGF  --- I have never used LyX, so I can't really answer, but if you hope to find a WYSIWYG interface to build the circuits, I fear it's not there.

Comment: OTOH, stadnalone is pretty fast for prototyping.

Comment: Wait, does the TikZ preamble automatically come with the logic circuits? Or would I have to make my own? Also, I used

`\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=pics/]`

to add the preamble to LyX (I'm on Windows), but I'm not sure if I did it right, since nothing popped up on my list of preambles